# startactivity() shuts app down

Tags: java, android

i have following activity,
when startactivity() is called the app is forced shut down, i am searching for the failure a few days already, can anybody help me?

app:

```
package com.example.deceunincktechniekers;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;



public class OpeningsMenu extends ListActivity {
//hier maken we de Array (lijst) met de namen die in de menu moeten komen
String classes[] = {"bezoekrapporten" ,"BTWcontrole" ,"voorbeeld3"};


// hier zetten we de layout van deze class niet gelijk aan een xml maar aan een            lijst van knoppen volgens simple list item 1
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(OpeningsMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

}
// hier zetten we de actie als er op de lijst geklikt wordt
//
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // 
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String positie = classes[position];
    try{
    Class onzeclass = Class.forName("com.example.deceunincktechniekers." + positie);
    Intent onzeIntent = new Intent(OpeningsMenu.this, onzeclass);
    startActivity(onzeIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
07-13 12:48:47.204: D/dalvikvm(785): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 8% free 2768K/2984K, paused 14ms+57ms, total 148ms
07-13 12:48:47.664: I/Choreographer(785): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-13 12:48:47.714: D/gralloc_goldfish(785): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-13 12:53:35.678: D/dalvikvm(785): newInstance failed: Lcom/example/deceunincktechniekers/bezoekrapporten; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
07-13 12:53:35.678: D/AndroidRuntime(785): Shutting down VM
07-13 12:53:35.678: W/dalvikvm(785): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deceunincktechniekers/com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-13 12:53:35.738: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  ... 11 more
07-13 12:53:38.838: I/Process(785): Sending signal. PID: 785 SIG: 9
```

if you need more info, please ask for it

Comment: `"com.example.deceunincktechniekers." + positie)` = have you declared all of these Activities in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either there is no class named `com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten`, or it is not `public`, or perhaps it has no `public` constructor.

Comment: there was `class bezoekrapporten extends...`, i changed to `public class bezoekrapportend extends ...`, now this button works, there seems to be another problem for my other buttons

Comment: @keuninkske: Activities (and any other component, like services) must be public classes with public zero-argument constructors. Usually the constructor is handled for you by the superclass, but you need to explicitly mark the class itself as `public`. That is because code outside of your package, from the Android framework, is responsible for creating instances of your components, and that is not possible if the classes are not public.

Answer (score 1):

Your log says

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException access to class not allowed

Probably the class, named

> com.example.deceunincktechniekers. + positie

doesnt have a public constructor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I checked the AndroidManifest.xml and the activity I wanted to call with *startActivity(Intent)* was missing.
After I added the activity (check below) I can call my Activity (Entry):